# Define interface as a combination of some predefined key (id: string) and key-access types ({ [key:string]: AnotherInterface })

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore

I have a specific use case where my database record has following data

```
{
  id: 'user_id_1',
  '26-08-23': [{...other object}],
  '27-08-23': [{...another object}]
  ...
}
```

I would like to know how I can create a typescript interface to support the above case.
The basic idea was to have two interfaces and see if I could extend but that doesn't work

```
export interface DateMappedObject {
  [date: string]: UserAttendanceDateMap
}

export interface UserAttendance extends DateMappedObject {
  id: string;
}
```

[image]

Can someone suggest a solution please?

---

**Tldr;**

**Why the object is shaped this way?**

- I'm using Firebase/firestore and I'm achieving two benefits with the above object
  The above approach allows me to get all of that data in one query
- The data is limited for each month, so the scalability issue is not a concern here)
- I'll use the dates to populate a calendar with data for a day and date-key allows quick access by index-key pattern.

Comment: This is a current pain point in TS and there's no perfect solution; a longstanding feature request at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) to allow it, but it's not implemented.  See the linked question and answers for various approaches